# Objects getting jerks when moving camera in downward direction

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been making a game in which there is number of objects in negative 'y' for which I had taken the arrayList and I am moving the main character in downward direction.But when the camera move with the character the objects are not moving smooth, they are getting jerks after some interval of time.The code for that is following

```
@Override
public void create() {
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(480, 720);
    camera.position.set(480 / 2, 720 / 2, 0);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    int i;

    this.baloonArrList = new ArrayList<Baloon>();

    for (i = 0; i < 3000; i += 300) {
        Baloon baloon = new Baloon(200, i);
        baloonArrList.add(baloon);
        System.out.println(baloon.balloon_y);
    }
    texture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/sheet_final.png"));
    textureRegion1 = new TextureRegion(texture1, 561, 156, 115, 101);
}

@Override
public void render() {

    GLCommon gl = Gdx.gl;
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.position.y += 4;
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    int len = baloonArrList.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        batch.draw(textureRegion1, baloonArrList.get(i).balloon_x,
                baloonArrList.get(i).balloon_y, 100, 100);
    }

    batch.end();

}
```

So, how can I make the motion of objects smooth.

Comment: Does the problem occur on Android, desktop or both?

Comment: @RodHyde It's coming on both.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the source of your issue is the following line:

```
camera.position.y += 4;
```

You should instead change it to a smaller value, or better, make it based on the speed of the frame rate:

```
camera.position.y += 4 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

This way your camera will move in the y direction 4 pixels every second, instead of 4 pixels every frame. (Of course you may need to increase the 4 to make it faster, but it will keep it quite smooth.)

Answer (score 0):

If the rendering is jerky and inconsistent (use [the builtin `FPSLogger`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/FPSLogger.html) to find out what framerate you're getting), then something is taking more/variable amounts of time during rendering.  You should use a profiler to figure out where time is going.  The Android DDMS tools included with Eclipse are pretty good.  Too-frequent garbage collection is often a source of variable runtimes, but its best to understand what is going on before trying to fix it.

That said, @Jyro117's suggestion to make your state updates frame-rate independent is always a good idea.